# Swift protocol generic as function return type

Tags: swift, generics

I want to use generic protocol type as a function return type like this:

```
protocol P {
  associatedtype T
  func get() -> T?
  func set(v: T)
}

class C<T>: P {
  private var v: T?
  func get() -> T? {
    return v
  }
  func set(v: T) {
    self.v = v
  }
}

class Factory {
  func createC<T>() -> P<T> {
    return C<T>()
  }
}
```

But this code compile with errors complained:

1. Cannot specialize non-generic type 'P'
2. Generic parameter 'T' is not used in function signature

Is there any way to achieve similar function with Swift？

Comment: Which lines have the errors? I think I have a good idea where #2 is but not #1.

Comment: @TroyT The line with code `func createC<T>() -> P<T> {`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is you cannot use the syntax `P<T>`. `P` is a protocol, meaning it can't be treated as a generic type (`Cannot specialize non-generic type 'P'`), even though it may have a given `associatedtype`.

In fact, *because* it has an `associatedtype`, you now can't even use the protocol type itself directly – you can only use it as a generic constraint.

One solution to your problem is to simply change your function signature to `createC<T>() -> C<T>`, as that's exactly what it returns.

```
class Factory {
    func createC<T>() -> C<T> {
        return C<T>()
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what you would gain from having the return type be a protocol here. Presumably your example is just a simplification of your actual code and you want to be able to return an arbitrary instance that conforms to `P`. In that case, you could use [type erasure](http://robnapier.net/erasure):

```
class AnyP<T> : P {

    private let _get : () -> T?
    private let _set : (T) -> ()

    init<U:P where U.T == T>(_ base:U) {
        _get = base.get
        _set = base.set
    }

    func get() -> T? {return _get()}
    func set(v: T) {_set(v)}
}
```

```
class Factory {
    func createC<T>() -> AnyP<T> {
        return AnyP(C<T>())
    }
}
```

Comment: Did something changed for now? https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-a-protocol-associated-type

Answer (score 10):

Swift 5.1 supports returning associated types using Opaque type. Using opaque type, your code builds successfully. [Ref](https://medium.com/@alfianlosari/understanding-opaque-return-types-in-swift-9c36fb5dfa86)

```
protocol P {
    associatedtype T
    func get() -> T?
    func set(v: T)
}

class C<T>: P {
    private var v: T?

    func get() -> T? {
        return v
    }
    func set(v: T) {
        self.v = v
    }
}

class Factory {
    func createC<T>() -> some P {
        return C<T>()
}
```